Extracting from a column containing a list of structs, using another column containing values a field of the structs much match
Consider the example:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series(
            "id",
            ["alpha", "beta"],
        ),
        pl.Series(
            "s",
            [
                [{"x": 0, "y": "a"}, {"x": 1, "y": "b"}, {"x": 0, "y": "c"}],
                [{"x": 0, "y": "b"}, {"x": 1, "y": "a"}, {"x": 1, "y": "c"}],
            ],
        ),
        pl.Series("selector", [0, 1]),
    ]
)
print(df)
# shape: (2, 3)
# ┌───────┬─────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
# │ id    ┆ s                           ┆ selector │
# │ ---   ┆ ---                         ┆ ---      │
# │ str   ┆ list[struct[2]]             ┆ i64      │
# ╞═══════╪═════════════════════════════╪══════════╡
# │ alpha ┆ [{0,"a"}, {1,"b"}, {0,"c"}] ┆ 0        │
# │ beta  ┆ [{0,"b"}, {1,"a"}, {1,"c"}] ┆ 1        │
# └───────┴─────────────────────────────┴──────────┘

first_try = df.with_columns(
    extracted=pl.col("s")
    .list.eval(
        pl.when(pl.element().struct.field("x").eq(pl.col("selector")))
        .then(pl.element().struct.field("y"))
        .otherwise(None)
    )
    .list.drop_nulls()
)
print(first_try)
# error: ComputeError: named columns are not allowed in `list.eval`; consider using `element` or `col("")`

other_try = df.join(
    df.explode("s")
    .filter(pl.col("s").struct.field("x").eq(pl.col("selector")))
    .with_columns(extracted=pl.col("s").struct.field("y"))
    .group_by("id")
    .agg(pl.col("extracted")),
    on="id",
)
print(other_try)
# shape: (2, 4)
# ┌───────┬─────────────────────────────┬──────────┬────────────┐
# │ id    ┆ s                           ┆ selector ┆ extracted  │
# │ ---   ┆ ---                         ┆ ---      ┆ ---        │
# │ str   ┆ list[struct[2]]             ┆ i64      ┆ list[str]  │
# ╞═══════╪═════════════════════════════╪══════════╪════════════╡
# │ alpha ┆ [{0,"a"}, {1,"b"}, {0,"c"}] ┆ 0        ┆ ["a", "c"] │
# │ beta  ┆ [{0,"b"}, {1,"a"}, {1,"c"}] ┆ 1        ┆ ["a", "c"] │
# └───────┴─────────────────────────────┴──────────┴────────────┘

first_try does not work, but other_try does. The error with first_try is:
ComputeError: named columns are not allowed in `list.eval`; consider using `element` or `col("")`

Which lead me to: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7210
Where the suggestion is to use group_by, which is what lead me to other_try. I am wondering if I might have misunderstood the suggestion though, or if there's another way? Perhaps something using something like how the "walrus operator" is used here?

If you add the item to the list, it is possible to use inside list.eval()
Putting it as the first item allows you to refer to it easily as pl.element().first()
You can then .slice(1) to remove it from the result.
df.with_columns(
   pl.concat_list(pl.struct(x="selector"), "s")
     .list.eval(
        pl.element().filter(
           pl.element().struct["x"] == pl.element().first().struct["x"]
        )
        .slice(1) 
        .struct["y"]
     )
     .alias("extracted")
)

shape: (2, 4)
┌───────┬─────────────────────────────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ id    ┆ s                           ┆ selector ┆ extracted  │
│ ---   ┆ ---                         ┆ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ list[struct[2]]             ┆ i64      ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════════════╪══════════╪════════════╡
│ alpha ┆ [{0,"a"}, {1,"b"}, {0,"c"}] ┆ 0        ┆ ["a", "c"] │
│ beta  ┆ [{0,"b"}, {1,"a"}, {1,"c"}] ┆ 1        ┆ ["a", "c"] │
└───────┴─────────────────────────────┴──────────┴────────────┘

There is also a request for a .list.filter() which could perhaps simplify such an operation in the future.

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9189


You could also explode, unnest, filter, then group_by + agg, and join:
out = df.join(
    df.explode('s')
    .unnest('s')
    .filter(pl.col('x') == pl.col('selector'))
    .group_by('id')
    .agg(pl.col('y').alias('extracted')),
    on='id',
)

Output:
┌───────┬─────────────────────────────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ id    ┆ s                           ┆ selector ┆ extracted  │
│ ---   ┆ ---                         ┆ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ list[struct[2]]             ┆ i64      ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════════════╪══════════╪════════════╡
│ alpha ┆ [{0,"a"}, {1,"b"}, {0,"c"}] ┆ 0        ┆ ["a", "c"] │
│ beta  ┆ [{0,"b"}, {1,"a"}, {1,"c"}] ┆ 1        ┆ ["a", "c"] │
└───────┴─────────────────────────────┴──────────┴────────────┘


I could, but does that mean I should? For instance, if exploding s requires extra memory (often the case with explode operations) at least temporarily, then it might not be a good idea, because reducing peak run-time memory usage is probably a good thing. On the other hand, if doing this is much faster, then well, there's a tradeoff to be made. So, is there a tradeoff to be made that's worthwhile?

That's a very good point, the best would be to test it on real-life data. I don't have a lot of perspective on polars, but with other dataframe libraries I've sometimes been surprised by approaches I would have believed not to be efficient. jqurious's solution seems efficient.

Just to add another possibility, you can also use DuckDB integration with Polars, which at the moment has a bit better support for list operations.

list_filter() to filter out elements.
list_transform() to extract item you need from the struct.
pl() to convert it back to polars dataframe.

import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        *,
        list_transform(list_filter(s, x -> x['x'] == selector), x -> x['y']) as extracted
    from df;
""").pl()

shape: (2, 4)
┌───────┬─────────────────────────────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ id    ┆ s                           ┆ selector ┆ extracted  │
│ ---   ┆ ---                         ┆ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ list[struct[2]]             ┆ i64      ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════════════╪══════════╪════════════╡
│ alpha ┆ [{0,"a"}, {1,"b"}, {0,"c"}] ┆ 0        ┆ ["a", "c"] │
│ beta  ┆ [{0,"b"}, {1,"a"}, {1,"c"}] ┆ 1        ┆ ["a", "c"] │
└───────┴─────────────────────────────┴──────────┴────────────┘


Oh this is quite neat. Upvote from me :) I wonder though: how expensive is it to "convert" back and forth between the DuckDB and Polars?
